# Using Generics and extending Abstract classes

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I've researched this issue a great deal, but have not been very successful in finding a solution close to my situation. I apologize if I am redundant.

Anyway, I am new to generics and so I'm not entirely clear on the syntax. But here is my situation:

I have an Interface (let's call it *IService*) and an implementation (*ServiceImpl*). The implementation class has an abstract method that is to be overridden by an extending class (*ServiceExt*).

I have an abstract bean (let's call it *AbstractBean*) which has a few fields and is meant to be extended by another bean (*BeanExt*) in order to add some more fields.

Ok, now that the situation is laid out, here is my abbreviated code:

**Interface:**

```
public interface IService <B extends AbstractBean> {
    B method(B bean, Object data) throws Exception;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public abstract class ServiceImpl <B extends AbstractBean> implements IService<B> {
    public abstract B method(B bean, Object data);
}
```

**Abstract Bean**:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean{

    private String fname;

    private String lname;

    [getters and setters]
}
```

**Extended Bean:**

```
public class BeanExt extends AbstractBean{

    private String phoneNum;

    [getter and setter]
}
```

**Extending Class:** aka Class giving me issues

```
public class ServiceExt <B extends AbstractBean> extends ServiceImpl <B> {

    @Override
    public <B> BeanExt method(Bbean, Object data) {
        if(beaninstanceof AbstractBean){
            BeanExt beanExt = (BeanExt) session;
            beanExt.setFname("John");
            beanExt.setLname("Doe");
            beanExt.setPhoneNum("123456789");
            return beanExt;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so now eclipse is giving me all kinds of non-descriptive issues and I don't know what to do. I've played around with the extending class methods a ton but have not found success. Above is how it looks after my last tinkering.

The issues currently presented by my IDE within the class *ServiceExt* are:

- The method method(B, Object) of type ServiceImpl must override or implement a supertype method
- The type ServiceExt  must implement the inherited abstract method [some other non-abstract method in the interface]

---

**Edit:** For further clarification, what I am ultimately trying to do is:

- Create a bean which extends the AbstractBean and add another field
- Define the abstract method inside the class ServiceExt
- Within the method, set some values in the extended bean
- Return the extended bean with its new values

**Update** - I've taken all of your input and the changes are reflected below. The issue currently presented by my IDE within the class *ServiceExt* is:

- **The type ServiceExt  must implement the inherited abstract method [some other non-abstract method in the interface]**

**Interface:**

```
public interface IService <B extends AbstractBean> {
    B method(B bean, Object data) throws Exception;
    B otherMethod(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public abstract class ServiceImpl <B extends AbstractBean> implements IService<B> {
    public abstract B method(B bean, Object data);

    @Override
    public final B otherMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return [something]; 
    }
}
```

**Abstract Bean**:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean{

    private String fname;

    private String lname;

    [getters and setters]
}
```

**Extended Bean:**

```
public class BeanExt extends AbstractBean{

    private String phoneNum;

    [getter and setter]
}
```

**Extending Class:** aka Class giving me issues

```
public class ServiceExt extends ServiceImpl <BeanExt> {

    @Override
    public BeanExt method(BeanExt bean, Object data) {
        BeanExt beanExt = (BeanExt) session;
        beanExt.setFname("John");
        beanExt.setLname("Doe");
        beanExt.setPhoneNum("123456789");
        return beanExt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `ServiceImpl` does not compile. Is `implements IService<S>` a typo? It should be `implements IService<B>`. Please check.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been corrected

Comment: I'm confused. It seemed we all solved your first problem (i.e. compiler errors). Has your problem now changed? Note that this makes it rather difficult to help you.

Comment: "*I've taken all of your input*" > Several of us have provided input that should solve your other problem too. Have you read through the answers?

Comment: I have read through the answers and I no longer have any issues with the method. My issue is now that eclipse is prompting me to implement an inherited abstract method, which is in fact not abstract at all.

I have edited to show that method within the Interface and the Implementation.

Comment: What? Have you modified your question based on answers? All the answers are now void.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have restored the original question and added all updates below the "Edit" line.

Comment: @Mike Your modified code should work fine.

Comment: @Duncan He has implemented it in `ServiceImpl` class.

Comment: @Rohit I believe that to be true as well, yet Eclipse tells me that I have another inherited abstract method to implement. I thought that that might possibly be due to some error in defining the methods in my interface or implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really overriding the method in super class. Here's the overridden method:

```
@Override
public BeanExt method(BeanExt bean, Object data) {
        BeanExt beanExt = (BeanExt) session;
        beanExt.setFname("John");
        beanExt.setLname("Doe");
        beanExt.setPhoneNum("123456789");
        return beanExt;
}
```

Since you're extending from `ServiceImpl<BeanExt>`, the type parameter `B` is replaced with `BeanExt` type, so does the return type and parameter of the method.

Also note that I've removed the `instanceof` check, as it is really not needed. `bean` will always be an instance of `AbstractBean`, because that is enforced by the bound you gave to the type parameter declaration of `ServiceImpl` class.

Answer (score 0):

I did not entirely understand what you're trying to do, but is this acceptable/working?

```
public class ServiceExt <B extends BeanExt> extends ServiceImpl <B> {

    @Override
    public B method(B bean, Object data) {
        bean.setFname("John");
        bean.setLname("Doe");
        bean.setPhoneNum("123456789");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected all the errors:

```
interface IService <B extends AbstractBean> {
    B method(B bean, Object data) throws Exception;
}

abstract class ServiceImpl <B extends AbstractBean> implements IService<B> {
    public abstract B method(B bean, Object data);
}

abstract class AbstractBean{

    String fname;
    String lname;
}

class BeanExt extends AbstractBean {

    String phoneNum;
}

class ServiceExt <B extends AbstractBean> extends ServiceImpl <B> {

    @Override public B method(B bean, Object data) {
        if (bean instanceof BeanExt) {
            BeanExt beanExt = (BeanExt) bean;
            beanExt.fname = "John";
            beanExt.lname = "Doe";
            beanExt.phoneNum = "123456789";
            return bean;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```